# Burp Scanner-License Issue. Experts suggestions please

Tags: appexchange, security-review, burp, zap-scanner

We are planning to submit our app in AppExchange. We have succeeded in generating **ZAP** but we were also asked to submit **BURP** Scanner report. But the issue with Burp is that, the professional edition have the features that supports OWASP top 10 but the free version doesn't support the same.

**Links that contradicts:**

https://www.facebook.com/SalesforceHelp/posts/10152809977822916

https://portswigger.net/burp/

https://security.secure.force.com/security/partners

Web application scanner license requests
when we click the above link we got authorization required. How to proceed from this?

As per Salesforce documentation, only the Partner can request a BURP License. Do we need to buy Burp Scanner to generate the report??

I realize this isn't a true Salesforce question, but I'm sure other developers have been asked/will be asked to do this during the submission process for AppExchange and I could do with some help. Experts suggestions please.